# Python function and list

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list

Нужно создать функцию которая принимает список с числами а возвращает: #
.

```
  h = func([2, 6, 3, 1])
  print(h)
  ##
  ######
  ###
  #
```

Объясните что не так с моим вариантом решения

```
    list_1 = [ ]
    i = 0
    while i < len(list_1):
        print(int(list_1[i]) * "#")
        i += 1
    return list_1
```

Comment: `print(*[ "#"*i for i in [2, 6, 3, 1] ], sep='\n')`

Comment: У Вас в цикл даже не заходит. Вы создаёте пустой список, а затем пытаетесь войти в цикл по условию `0 < длина пустого списка`, т.е. `0 < 0`, что является `False`.

Comment: Как тогда написать функцию что бы не задавать ей значения внутри а чтобы она использовала те, которые берутся из списка извне?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def func(list_1):

    i = 0
    while i < len(list_1):
        print(int(list_1[i]) * "#")
        i += 1
    return list_1


func([2, 6, 3, 1])
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, а можете, пожалуйста, объяснить почему мне не нужно было писать строчку ( list_1 = [ ] )тем самым обозначая, что я беру в расчет список

Comment: У вас этот список приходит в функцию в качестве аргумента. Поэтому отдельно его создавать внутри функции не нужно.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо)